# how to add new rule to selinux to access /dev/ttyHSL uart device?

Tags: file, security, permissions, policy, selinux

I am working on Android 9 provided by qualcomm. There are two uart devices /dev/ttyHSL0, /dev/ttyHSL1. ttyHSL0 is used for console and ttyHSL1 for communicating another chip. But my application cannot open /dev/ttyHSL1 device successfully.
it gives;

03-21 13:27:17.635 10303 10303 W edev.serialtool: type=1400 audit(0.0:23): avc: denied { read } for name="ttyHSL1" dev="tmpfs" ino=16426 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:serial_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0

when i set selinux to permisive mode in console, it works. But it needs to be permanent.
How can i add necessary rule to solve this problem?

Thank you very much and

keep yourself away from the coronavirus
stay@home